# Flexbox issue - heights not equal

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have created a flex box, please see codepen link here:- https://codepen.io/scottYg55/pen/zYYWbJG.

I want the pink backgrounds of this flexbox to be 50% height and the background image 50% height too, so it looks more of a grid system.

For some reason the pink BG is not expanding its width no matter what I try, I just want the images and Pink BG to all be the exact same height. Maybe CSS grid would be better?

If someone could help that would be great!

HTML

```
<div class="blog-contl row">



        <div class="col">
          <div class="blog-half">
          <div class="blog-half-img" style="background-image:url('http://www.project-progress.co.uk/cloudhouse/site/wp-content/uploads/blog6.jpg')">
          </div>
          <div class="blog-half-cont">
            <h4>Test Post 12</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</p>
            <div class="main-button">
              <a href="http://www.project-progress.co.uk/cloudhouse/site/test-post-12/" title="Read More" class="btn-default">Read More</a>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      </div>



        <div class="col">
          <div class="blog-half">
          <div class="blog-half-img" style="background-image:url('http://www.project-progress.co.uk/cloudhouse/site/wp-content/uploads/blog3.jpg')">
          </div>
          <div class="blog-half-cont">
            <h4>Test Post 9</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</p>
            <div class="main-button">
              <a href="http://www.project-progress.co.uk/cloudhouse/site/test-post-9/" title="Read More" class="btn-default">Read More</a>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      </div>



        <div class="col">
          <div class="blog-half">
          <div class="blog-half-img" style="background-image:url('http://www.project-progress.co.uk/cloudhouse/site/wp-content/uploads/blog6.jpg')">
          </div>
          <div class="blog-half-cont">
            <h4>Test Post 6</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</p>
            <div class="main-button">
              <a href="http://www.project-progress.co.uk/cloudhouse/site/test-post-6/" title="Read More" class="btn-default">Read More</a>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      </div>



</div>
```

CSS

```
.row {display:flex;}

.blog-contl img {width:auto;}

.blog-contl .row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.blog-contl .col {padding:0;}

.blog-half {
}

.blog-half-img {
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 50%;
}

.blog-half-cont {
    background: #da55c9;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 40px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}

.blog-half {display:flex;flex-wrap:wrap;}

.col:nth-of-type(2) .blog-half .blog-half-cont {
  order:1;
}

.col:nth-of-type(2) .blog-half .blog-half-img {
  order:2;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: if you use `display:flex` only the direct childrens are flex-items. So you should remove the `.col` and `.blog-half` elements. Then you can use `align-items: stretch` on the parent.

Comment: don't think you can do this with flex over 2 rows unless you have a fixed height

Comment: Do you recommend the best way to do this? I want to change the order of the 2nd column too

Answer (score 0):

It is better to you use grid instead of flex. Please use the below code.
Note: We have used grid to adjust the height.

```css
.row { display: grid; grid: auto /auto auto auto; }
        .blog-half { display: grid; grid-auto-rows: 1fr; }
        .blog-contl img {width:auto;}
        .blog-half-img {
            background-size: cover;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            width: 100%;
            padding-bottom: 50%;
        }
        .blog-half-cont {
            background: #da55c9;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 40px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            text-align: center;
            color: #fff;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: center;
        }
        .col:nth-of-type(2) .blog-half .blog-half-cont {
          order:1;
        }

        .col:nth-of-type(2) .blog-half .blog-half-img {
          order:2;
        }
```

```html
<div class="blog-contl row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="blog-half">
                <div class="blog-half-img" style="background-image:url('http://www.project-progress.co.uk/cloudhouse/site/wp-content/uploads/blog6.jpg')">
                </div>
                <div class="blog-half-cont">
                    <h4>Test Post 12</h4>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</p>
                    <div class="main-button">
                        <a href="http://www.project-progress.co.uk/cloudhouse/site/test-post-12/" title="Read More" class="btn-default">Read More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="blog-half">
                <div class="blog-half-img" style="background-image:url('http://www.project-progress.co.uk/cloudhouse/site/wp-content/uploads/blog3.jpg')">
                </div>
                <div class="blog-half-cont">
                    <h4>Test Post 9</h4>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</p>
                    <div class="main-button">
                        <a href="http://www.project-progress.co.uk/cloudhouse/site/test-post-9/" title="Read More" class="btn-default">Read More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col ">
            <div class="blog-half">
                <div class="blog-half-img" style="background-image:url('http://www.project-progress.co.uk/cloudhouse/site/wp-content/uploads/blog6.jpg')">
                </div>
                <div class="blog-half-cont">
                    <h4>Test Post 6</h4>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</p>
                    <div class="main-button">
                        <a href="http://www.project-progress.co.uk/cloudhouse/site/test-post-6/" title="Read More" class="btn-default">Read More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```